# Spring Boot 3, Postgres and JPARepository method with Pageable as argument

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Upgrading to Spring Boot 3, it turned out that JPARepository methods with Pageable as argument throw an Exception using postgres as a database. No problems with MariaDb. Also, running the query directly on the database works fine.

```
@Query(value = "select a from Author a where lower(a.fullName) like (:fullName) ")  
Page<Author> findByLowerFullName(@Param("fullName") String fullName, Pageable pageable);
```

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.0.2)

2023-01-25T12:30:10.307Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] is.landsbokasafn.audb.web.App            : Starting App using Java 17 with PID 2032 (E:\workspaces-all\gits\AUDB2\audb-web\target\classes started by georg in E:\workspaces-all\gits\AUDB2\audb-web)
2023-01-25T12:30:10.308Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] is.landsbokasafn.audb.web.App            : The following 1 profile is active: "web-development"
2023-01-25T12:30:10.338Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2023-01-25T12:30:10.339Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2023-01-25T12:30:10.670Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2023-01-25T12:30:10.700Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 26 ms. Found 2 JPA repository interfaces.
2023-01-25T12:30:10.986Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] i.l.audb.web.config.WebConfiguration     : ajpEnabled: true
2023-01-25T12:30:11.101Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8906 (ajp)
2023-01-25T12:30:11.106Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8906"]
2023-01-25T12:30:11.107Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-01-25T12:30:11.107Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.5]
2023-01-25T12:30:11.134Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/audb]   : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-01-25T12:30:11.134Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 795 ms
2023-01-25T12:30:11.240Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2023-01-25T12:30:11.263Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.1.6.Final
2023-01-25T12:30:11.333Z  WARN 2032 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000021: Encountered deprecated setting [javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode], use [jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode] instead
2023-01-25T12:30:11.385Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2023-01-25T12:30:11.473Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@6a0db419
2023-01-25T12:30:11.474Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2023-01-25T12:30:11.498Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] SQL dialect                              : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
2023-01-25T12:30:11.986Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2023-01-25T12:30:11.991Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2023-01-25T12:30:12.220Z  WARN 2032 --- [  restartedMain] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: is.landsbokasafn.audb.data.dao.TermDAO
2023-01-25T12:30:12.253Z  WARN 2032 --- [  restartedMain] ocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer : Using deprecated '-debug' fallback for parameter name resolution. Compile the affected code with '-parameters' instead or avoid its introspection: is.landsbokasafn.audb.data.dao.AuthorDAO
2023-01-25T12:30:12.536Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2023-01-25T12:30:12.539Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 4 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2023-01-25T12:30:12.571Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpNioProtocol     : Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8906"]
2023-01-25T12:30:12.588Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8906 (ajp) with context path '/audb'
2023-01-25T12:30:12.596Z  INFO 2032 --- [  restartedMain] is.landsbokasafn.audb.web.App            : Started App in 2.517 seconds (process running for 2.862)
2023-01-25T12:30:17.671Z  INFO 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/audb]   : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-25T12:30:17.671Z  INFO 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-01-25T12:30:17.672Z  INFO 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
Hibernate: select a1_0.id,a1_0.born_year,a1_0.description,a1_0.died_year,a1_0.feature,a1_0.full_name,a1_0.last_modified,a1_0.prefered_author from author a1_0 where lower(a1_0.full_name) like ? escape '' order by a1_0.full_name asc offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
2023-01-25T12:30:20.155Z TRACE 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [$n%]
2023-01-25T12:30:20.156Z TRACE 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [0]
2023-01-25T12:30:20.156Z TRACE 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-3] org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind              : binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - [50]
2023-01-25T12:30:20.159Z  WARN 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-01-25T12:30:20.159Z ERROR 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"
  Position: 249
2023-01-25T12:30:20.164Z  INFO 2032 --- [0.1-8906-exec-3] i.l.audb.web.controller.ExceptionAdvice  : Error resolving URL https://lbs-ut02.landsbokasafn.is/audb/browseAuthors/$N/STARTS_WITH

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select a1_0.id,a1_0.born_year,a1_0.description,a1_0.died_year,a1_0.feature,a1_0.full_name,a1_0.last_modified,a1_0.prefered_author from author a1_0 where lower(a1_0.full_name) like ? escape '' order by a1_0.full_name asc offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only]; SQL [n/a]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:550) ~[spring-orm-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:134) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:218) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy139.findByLowerFullName(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at is.landsbokasafn.audb.data.service.AuthorService.find(AuthorService.java:78) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:703) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at is.landsbokasafn.audb.data.service.AuthorService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.find(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at is.landsbokasafn.audb.web.controller.AuthorController.browsesubjects(AuthorController.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ServerHttpObservationFilter.doFilterInternal(ServerHttpObservationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:440) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select a1_0.id,a1_0.born_year,a1_0.description,a1_0.died_year,a1_0.feature,a1_0.full_name,a1_0.last_modified,a1_0.prefered_author from author a1_0 where lower(a1_0.full_name) like ? escape '' order by a1_0.full_name asc offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:253) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.getResultSet(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:205) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.processNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.AbstractJdbcValues.next(AbstractJdbcValues.java:29) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.next(RowProcessingStateStandardImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.spi.ListResultsConsumer.consume(ListResultsConsumer.java:33) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.doExecuteQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.executeQuery(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.internal.JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.list(JdbcSelectExecutorStandardImpl.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.sql.exec.spi.JdbcSelectExecutor.list(JdbcSelectExecutor.java:31) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.lambda$new$0(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.withCacheableSqmInterpretation(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.performList(ConcreteSqmSelectQueryPlan.java:276) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.doList(QuerySqmImpl.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.spi.AbstractSelectionQuery.list(AbstractSelectionQuery.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.QuerySqmImpl.list(QuerySqmImpl.java:1073) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$PagedExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:90) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:148) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:136) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.0.1.jar:3.0.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
    ... 78 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$3"
  Position: 249
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:134) ~[postgresql-42.5.1.jar:42.5.1]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.DeferredResultSetAccess.executeQuery(DeferredResultSetAccess.java:217) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.6.Final.jar:6.1.6.Final]
    ... 110 common frames omitted
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>       
        </dependency>   
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf (templating) -->        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
        
        
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>quick-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.3</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.jpenren</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache commons utils -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging (capture Tomcat logging) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- i18n language names -->
        
    
        
        <!-- PostgreSQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
         


        <!-- Apache commons -->
        
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                    <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
              </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
            <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
       
        
        
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
        
        
        
    </dependencies>
```

I´ve been upgrading many projects to Spring Boot 3 with MariaDb without major problems, but now I´m stuck.
Is this a postgres, hibernate or spring boot problem? I also tried older postgres drivers, but no luck either.

Comment: Looking at the generated query it seems that jpql pagination translates to `offset n rows fetch m rows only` If I recall correctly, spring boot 2 was producing `offset n limit m` syntax, but i can't really find any information on that. Does your PostgreSQL version support this syntax? I'd recommend to copy that query, replace placeholders with some actual values and try it using dbeaver or some other client.

Comment: I would also suggest looking into which driver you are using for postgresql, your POM says runtime which means it is likely an existing version you have rather than a new updated one. You may want to change that to https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.5.1

Comment: My postgres version is: PostgreSQL 9.6.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit 
Running the queries in Navicat, both versions work: 
`offset n rows fetch m rows only` (used by Spring Boot 3.0.2) 
and `offset n limit m` (used by Spring Boot 2.7.7). 
Using postgres driver 42.5.1 explicity does not help.

Comment: Adding `spring.jpa.database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect` to the config solves the problem (produces `offset n limit m`).
Strange enough as i use PostgreSQL 9.6.3, and using `PostgreSQL9Dialect` does not work.
However, PostgreSQL82Dialect causes other problems like auto Id generation ...

Comment: So it seems to affect only PostgreSQL 9.6.3. Using 9.6.24 or 11.17.1 there are no problems at all.

Comment: We got same problem, and we gave up... We took benefit we need to upgrade to  PostgreSQL 12.11, and changed dialect to basic PostgreSQLDialect. Works like a charm.