# Spring 3.0.2 Pagination Issue with PostgreSQL

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I have migrated to spring 3.0.2 .But pagination with PostgreSQL database is not working because earlier "limit" is generating after end of the query but now "fetch rows ? only" generating and pagination object data is not being replaced with ? mark. Can anyone help?

I have tried by passing pagination object to repository method but it is throwing an error.

Comment: Please post code snippets, especially of the SQL that gets generated.

That said, this is probably a Hibernate bug. What is the Hibernate version you are using? Have you tried upgrading to the latest one?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duplicates:

[JPA 3 Hibernate + PostgreSQL 9.6.3 errors in queries with limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75244561/jpa-3-hibernate-postgresql-9-6-3-errors-in-queries-with-limitation)

[Spring Boot 3, Postgres and JPARepository method with Pageable as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75234293/spring-boot-3-postgres-and-jparepository-method-with-pageable-as-argument)

Problem is with postgres db version.

Comment: I have tried both the option but not working.